# jqgrid horizontal scrollbar issue in IE9

Tags: jqgrid

IE 9 displays a horizontal scrollbar on jqgrid which is not the case when rendered in chrome or mozilla.

following are the default configurations that i set when i create my jqgrid

```
datatype: "local",

colNames: ['Name', 'Note Type', 'Based On', 'Version', 'Status', 'Description', 'Id', 'Tags', 'TemplateId', 'TemplateVersionId', 'IsLocked'],

colModel: [
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', title: false, resizable: false, width: 175, classes: 'grid-pointer' },
                { name: 'NoteType', index: 'NoteType', width: 100, title: false, resizable: false, classes: 'grid-pointer', cellattr: function () { return 'style="white-space: normal";"height:auto";"vertical-align:text-top;"'; } },
                { name: 'BasedOn', index: 'BasedOn', width: 100, title: false, resizable: false, classes: 'grid-pointer', cellattr: function () { return 'style="white-space: normal";"height:auto";"vertical-align:text-top;"'; } },
                { name: 'Version', index: 'Version', classes: 'grid-pointer', align: "right", width: 50, title: false, resizable: false },
                { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 80, classes: 'grid-pointer', title: false, resizable: false },
                { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', title: false, resizable: false, width: 135, formatter: self.trimDescription, classes: 'grid-pointer' },
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, title: false },
                { name: 'Tags', index: 'Tags', hidden: true },
                { name: 'TemplateId', index: 'TemplateId', hidden: true },
                { name: 'TemplateVersionId', index: 'TemplateVersionId', hidden: true },
                { name: 'IsLocked', index: 'IsLocked', hidden: true}],
            sortname: 'Name',
            rowNum: 10,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            multiselect: false,
            autowidth:true,
            height: 'auto',
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#template-grid-pager',
            noRecordText: "No records to view",
```

Comment: Please, for the love of sanity, use code markup on your code. To do this, select that code, and then click the code button in the toolbar. There's no way I can parse that with the way it is right now.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) is detailed described how one can format the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I just disabled the overflow by calling the following function. In my case I am only doing it if the grid uses force fit, as all columns should fit then, however if you do not use force fit you can omit the conditional statement.

```
function jqGridDisableHScroll() {
    //if columns are force fit all columns will always fit on screen.
    if ($('#yourgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'forceFit')) {
        var gridview = $('#gview_yourgrid');
        $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv', gridview).css({ 'overflow-x': 'hidden' });
    }
}
```

Note: The reverse would need to be done though if column resizing is allowed and force fit is not on. Also you could just do this via css if it will be always the case for your grids